# What is the linux equivalent of openning a handle to PhysicalDrive and writing to MBR in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows

In Windows, you can easily open a handle to PhysicalDrive (or even \\.\c:) and write to the first sector of disk using WriteFile from user-mode, was wondering what is the equivalent c/c++ code of doing this Linux which requires the lowest privilege possible? is it possible to do this in Linux without running the code with sudo?

Basically I want to compile an ELF program that does exactly that but in Linux with lowest privilege possible, how can I do this? because in Windows you can do this from user-mode.

Also are SCSI PASSTROUGH DIRECT message possible in Linux as well for reading and writing to disk sectors? if so then how can I send a SCSI passthrough IRP message in Linux to disk driver to write to a file, in windows we can use DeviceIOcontrol to send the message ( sorry for the rookie questions, I'm not really familiar with programming in Linux )

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you **can't** write to the raw disk as a non-admin. MSDN: "The caller must have administrative privileges. "

Comment: Just wondering what type of Operating System would allow the most casual user the right to obliterate or steal every last shred of information stored on it? And who'd want to use it?

Comment: @MSalters My apology, it seems like that windows 7 runs the program as admin (integrity = high) by default even when I don't run it as admin for some reason , unlike windows 10, I edited the question

Comment: @MarkSetchell it is like that tho by default, because normal windows users just create an admin username, and for some reason windows 7 runs it as admin by default even  without the program forcing it to run as admin  or even user clicking it to run as admin for some unknown reason (even with maximum UAC it still runs it as admin without asking the user on my system!)

Comment: SCSI PASSTROUGH commands would only work with SCSI drives.

Comment: @stark yes but aren't most of the modern hard drives SCSI?

Comment: Almost none.  Most are either SATA or NVMe, neither of which use SCSI command set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In linux, every device is a file. So your first, physical harddrive could be /dev/sda . If you have sufficient permissions you could communicate (open, read and write) directly with your harddrive. After all .. it's just a file.

As for the privilege: Any user could do that, provided he/she has the required permission to do whatever you want with the specific device. That works via file permissions. For example you could add a user into a certain group and assign THIS group to your device, giving the group the required permissions via chmod.

You could also set the suid-bit for the program which does stuff with your physical drive. Meaning: If the user (he still needs execute-permissions for this program) starts it, the program iteself runs with another user id. Which could be root. Meaning: This process alone runs with elevated permissions, doing for the user what he/she couldn't do otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, a disk is often some block [device file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) such as `/dev/sda`. See [sd(4)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/sd.4.html) and [hd(4)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/hd.4.html).

The pseudofile `/proc/partitions` is giving the disk partitions. See [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and try `cat /proc/partitions` in a shell or terminal emulator.

You could have a [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) program accessing the disk. You would need [ioctl(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html). Beware: the *setuid* or *setgid* mechanism is tricky. Take several hours to understand it (or else you'll open a vulnerability).

For more, read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

On well configured Linux systems, `/dev/sda` is not accessible to all users. On Debian, it has:

```
% ls -l /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Jun 25 18:53 /dev/sda
```

so you might code a `disk` setgid ELF executable. See [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) and [capabilities(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) and [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)

Look also on [KernelNewbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/), study the [kernel](https://kernel.org/) source code, read about [initrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk) and [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd).

Study then improve the source code of GNU [parted](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/), since it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html).